# Calling a static method from an object inside a thread

Tags: c++

I have a static function inside a class:

```
class ABC {
  public: 
    static void calculate() 
    {
      //...
    }
};
```

I have another class:

```
Class DEF
{
  public:
    void doCalculation()
    {
      ABC::calculate();
    }
};
```

The object for class `DEF` is one per thread, that is, we have n number of threads which can access `calculate()` at the same time.

In this case should I lock the call `ABC::calculate()`?

Comment: That depends on what `calculate` *does*. Does it access data shared between threads?

Comment: It depends on the `...`

Comment: It would appear not ... ABC::calculate() has no parameters, so what it uses for the calculations  must be accessible by each thread.  Make it so by adding parameters to the method call.

Comment: The static calculate() method does not access any shared memory. It calls the getsockname() function by passing all local variables.

Comment: so you only read from local variables that are unchanged throughout the run of your application? That's guaranteed to be thread safe. However, if the local variables change, you'll need to make sure you get consistent views on the set of variables - you'll probably need locks or use memory ordering (not the easiest topic to get right).http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: i read from local variables that are unchanged. thankyou everyone for clarifying my doubt!

Answer (score 2):

Please think carefully: locks should protect *data*, not *code*. If you teach yourself to put locks around a function call, you'll be debugging forever.

Solutions:

- if `calculate()` only accesses static (not changing) data, no need
  for synchronization at all.
- if `calculate()` contains a simple increment of a shared variable
  (int/float), use [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). Note that atomics are *way*
  faster than any contended locking.
- if `calculate()` uses multiple variablers and/or larger structures, consider using [libguarded](https://github.com/copperspice/libguarded).
- if `calculate()` really is the only method accessing the data, use a `std::lock_guard<>`. At least you get exception safety for free.

Comment: If calculate() is simply code shared between threads, where there is no shared data (only variables declared in the method scope and the possible non reference/pointer parameters provided to the calculate method), then perhaps there is no need to use a lock/semaphore at all.
Cheers on the atomic reference. a very elegant synchronization tool.